# Return value from program function

Tags: pda, anchor-lang

Is it possible to return a custom value from a program function and capture this data in the client side code?

```
//Anchor function
pub fn new_item(ctx: Context<Item>, id: String) -> Result<String> {
   Ok("Custom return value");
}


//Client side
let customValue = await PROGRAM.methods.newItem()
            .accounts({
                item: itemPDA,
                user: user.publicKey,
            })
            .rpc();

console.log(customValue);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes! You can use [`set_return_data`](https://docs.rs/solana-sdk/latest/solana_sdk/program/fn.set_return_data.html) to write a slice of raw bytes to the return data.

```
solana_program::program::set_return_data(b"Custom return value");
```

When using the RPC's [`getTransaction`](https://docs.solana.com/api/http#gettransaction) method, you'll get the return data as a base64-encoded string, which you can then decode into the value, in this case a string.

You can find the return data in the transaction's `meta`.